# Using MSVC with QT creator: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted

Tags: qt, clang, llvm-clang

I'm using Qt Creator 4.7.2 and when I try to make a project using Desktop QT 5.11.2 with MSVC2015 32 bit compiler I get a repeating message under general messages:

```
Clang Code Model: Error: The clangbackend process has finished unexpectedly and was restarted.
```

This message is repeating 3 times every second and the text editor is very laggy as well. This only happens when I use the MSVC compiler, it works okay with MinGW. My code is just the basic window code that auto generates when you create a new project. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: That happens for some projects. Try to disable the clang plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Open `Help > About Plugins...`. Then, under `C++`, disable `ClangCodeModel`.